# Storing progress in session variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I am trying to implement a progressbar when a user executes find request in my web application(php/js/html).

When the user executes the find request, application executes php script using ajax, this script periodically stores its progress in session variable.

What I tried to do is to poll the server with another ajax request to ask for the session progress variable, but the variable does not exist.

Why is this happening, is this not possible using php sessions?

Thanks

**JS logic:**

```
// When the user selects interested object, find it on the server
$(document).on('change', '#findStreamer', function()
{
   $streamerId = $(this).val();
   $streamerName = $('#findStreamer option[value="'+$streamerId+'"]').text();
   console.log('findDB', $streamerId, $streamerName);
   addProgressBar();
   getProgress();

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'serverlink/findobject', 
            data: { 
                      findChannel: $streamerName,
                      checkOnline: true
                  },
            success: function(response) 
            {
                $streamData = JSON.parse(response);
                $('#streamPreview').remove();
               // $('#findPanelToolbar').before($streamData.streamerView);
                console.log($streamData);

            }

    });


});




 function getProgress()  
{
$.ajax({  
       type: 'POST',  
       url: 'serverlink/getprogress', 
       complete: getProgress,
       timeout: 60000,
       success: function(response) 
              {
                  $progresValue = response;
                  updateProgressBar($progresValue);

              }
         });
}
```

**Server logic:**

```
    public function action_findobject()
        {
            $_SESSION['percentage'] = 0;

            if(!(Input::is_ajax()))
            {
                $response = Response::forge();
                $response->set_status(400);
                return $response;
            }


// Long actions //

            $_SESSION['percentage'] = 10;


// Long actions //            

           $_SESSION['percentage'] = 45;


// Long actions //           


            $_SESSION['percentage'] = 100;

            return $Outputdata;



        }


public function action_getprogress()
{
    return $_SESSION['percentage'];


}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Did you remember `session_start();` ?

Comment: Yes the session start is set when the variable is written and read, I am using a php framework, for clarity I changed the code to normal php. The getprogress function always returns the default value if the variable is not found in the session.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need create php script, which will execute some tot big part of process and send json with %. Also percents need to be stored in session. In browser you will invoke ajax till get some error or result 100%. After you got answer from server, if percents<100 -> show new percent line to customer and do the same request to server..

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution so I'll wikify this but to answer the question, *"is this not possible using php sessions?"*... looks like a no - or at least not in the code's current form.  You would have to delegate the resource-intensive operation to another process somehow as the following simple test suggests that the first operation is **blocking**.

```php
<?php // sleep.php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['foo'] = gmdate('r');
    sleep(10);
```

```php
<?php // test.php
    session_start();
    echo !isset($_SESSION['foo'])
        ? 'session not set'
        : $_SESSION['foo'];
```

**Test:**

Browse **/sleep.php** which sets some value in the session then waits for 10 seconds (arbitrary) to mimic some exhaustive program/execution.  Open a new tab inside of the 10 second delay and browse **/test.php**.

**Expected Result:**

**/test.php** immediately returns the date that was set by **/sleep.php**

**Actual Result:**

**/test.php** request hung/waited until **/sleep.php** request had finished.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem using caching in a file, dont know how optimal that is, but thanks to everyone for your suggestions!